# VBA Using Range Expression from other sub

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 different  modules. One is triggering the other. Like that;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal TarGet As Range)
If Not Intersect(TarGet, Range("o7:o1000")) Is Nothing Then
Call dograma
End If
End Sub
```

And the other one is starting like that:

```
Sub dograma()

Txt = TarGet.Value
```

I get an error because  "TarGet" expression not defined in this sub. But I would like to use the same variable for both subs. Can I synchronize them?

Comment: Pass it as a parameter `Sub dograma(ByVal TarGet As Range)`.

Comment: It works. But I also need to change Call function in the first sub like that
Call dograma (TarGet)

Answer (score 1):

In second sub i changed name like that

```
Sub dograma(ByVal TarGet As Range)
```

and

In the first module I changed

```
Call Dograma
```

with

```
Call Dograma (TarGet)
```

It works well.

Comment: Note that use of `Call` is not required or useful.   It's a throwback to very early versions of VB.  Without it your call to Dograma becomes `Dograma Target`  (without the brackets)